# Genesis 2:9: נֶחְמָד לְמַרְאֶה versus Genesis 3:6: תַאֲוָה הוּא לָעֵינַיִם

Tags: genesis, hebrew

What is the relationship between נֶחְמָד לְמַרְאֶה in Genesis 2:9 and תַאֲוָה הוּא לָעֵינַיִם in Genesis 3:6? Is תַאֲוָה הוּא לָעֵינַיִם (KJV: “is pleasant to the sight”) simply a synonymous restatement of נֶחְמָד לְמַרְאֶה (KJV: “it was pleasant to the eyes”)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some shades of nuance.

In Gen 3.6, ṯaʾăwâ-hûʾ lāʿênayim -- the taʾăwâ has a sense of lust that is not present in 2.8. This adjective is used infrequently and within the Law only here and in Numbers 4.11 when the mixt multitude "fell a lusting" for meat to eat. It is a physical craving. It is paired with the biological "eyes" - this is literally "the lust of the eyes" in 1 John 2.16. Thus this is more about the flesh.

Whereas in Gen 2.9: neḥmāḏ ləmarʾe -- neḥmāḏ is a more generic "desire" as in the "thou shalt not covet", which refers to a broad range of things from desiring your neighbor's wife to your neighbor's status or property. It is also paired with the more abstract "sight".

Thus 3.6 is much more related to the body and a "lust" associated to the body whereas 2.8 is more abstract and generic.